# SQLite two primary keys

Tags: sql, sqlite, primary-key

I use a sqllite and I try to create this.

```
idText idNum  
sav      1    
abd      1     
sav      2 
sav      3
abd      2
```

Whith MySQL I did this but in sqllite is it possible?

the syntax in mysql is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTStest.animals;
CREATE TABLEtest.animals(
grpchar(30) NOT NULL,
idmediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
namechar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: i know the syntax to create composite key. but my problem is that one must be type int auto_increment

Comment: You mean `idNum` will be consecutive _for each `idText` group_?  Because right now `idNum` has duplicates so it can't be a true "autoincrement" column

Comment: D Stanley you're right!!!!

Comment: A composite primary key with an auto increment doesn't make sense. A primary key with an auto increment column will already be unique. Adding a second column to the PK won't make it more unique.